# Error implementing anychart circular gauge in vue

Tags: vuejs2, anychart

I'm evaluating Anychart's gauge component with Vue 2. The example from github works fine (with pie, bars and line graphs), but when I try to set the chart to the type 'gauge' or 'circular-gauge' it's not found. Are there any additional steps to follow in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The Circular Gauge requires adding the `Core` and `Circular Gauge` modules as stated in the [AnyChart Documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Gauges/Quick_Start). I guess you are missing the `Circular Gauge` module. Try adding that and refer to the documentation if you need additional information.